# Hive script is running long time

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive, emr

I am trying to run hive query on huge amount of data. The Geocode look up table have an ip-from and ip-to range that I have to compare against, a table of 1.8 million rows.

Hive Script:

```
select *
from ip_address a, ip_lookup b
where a.AddressInt >= b.ip_from and a.AddressInt <= b.ip_to;
```

On aws EMR, I'm running a cluster of c3.xlarge and during the running time it gets stuck at 67% for more than 1 day but here's the Hadoop job information for Stage-1:

```
Warning: Shuffle Join JOIN[4][tables = [a, b]] in Stage 'Stage-1:MAPRED' is a cross product
Stage-1: number of mappers: 6; number of reducers: 1
```

What should I do to improve the performance of this hive script?

Answer (score 1):

For improving the performance implement bucketing for the bigger table based on the joining field ( in your case it is IP address ) . For more information visit [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL+BucketedTables)

You can also implement smb join which is implemented by [Facebook](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/download/attachments/27362054/Hive%2BSummit%2B2011-join.pdf).